# How to add a featured image to a existing post via php?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails

I'm having trouble to add a featured image to an existing post via PHP. The image resides on wp-content/upload folder. The script i'm doing, is not a plugin, theme, or something like that. It's just an automation script that runs whenever it's called.

What is the best approach for this case?

Comment: Post your code please. Where is the code located? And when/how is it "called"?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is `media_sideload_image()` and `set_post_thumbnail()`. `media_sideload_image()`  assumes you can grab the URL to the image, whether it exist in `/wp-content/` or somewhere else (another site, even). As long as you can programmatically reference the image's URL, something like this should work.

```
$image = 'image.jpg';
$media = media_sideload_image($image, $post->ID);
if(!empty($media) && !is_wp_error($media)){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );

    // reference new image to set as featured
    $attachments = get_posts($args);

    if($attachments){
        foreach($attachments as $attachment){
            set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment->ID);
            // only want one image
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

- [Function Reference/media sideload image « WordPress
  Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image)
- [Function Reference/set post thumbnail « WordPress
  Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail)